# Bash Script Variable Scope inside Function

Tags: bash, shell, scope, sh

***THIS CODE ...***

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

getDeclared() {
    
    local v

    v=$( set -o posix ; set )
    IFS=$'\n' read -d '\034' -r -a v <<<"${v}\034"  
    
    echo "${v[*]}"
}

declare -a _hints=()
declare _hint="start.hint"
declare _paths
declare _basepath="root/devops/cloud"
declare _base="/"
declare _hintmaxdepth=0

    echo "${BASH_VERSION}"

    x=$(getDeclared)
    x=($x)
    
    for ((y=0;y<${#x[@]};y++)); do
        [ "${x[y]::1}" == "_" ] && echo "$y: ${x[y]}"$'\n'
    done
```

***HAS THIS OUTPUT:***

```
➜  sometest bash working.sh                                                                                                  
5.1.16(1)-release
66: _=posix

67: __CFBundleIdentifier=com.sublimetext.4

68: __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F6:0x0:0x0

69: _base=/

70: _basepath=root/devops/cloud

71: _hint=start.hint

72: _hintmaxdepth=0

73: _hints=()
```

***SO FAR SO GOOD***

However, if I change the function to include the display logic, as seen in ...

***THIS CODE ...***

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

getDeclared() {
    
    local v
    local x

    v=$( set -o posix ; set )
    IFS=$'\n' read -d '\034' -r -a v <<<"${v}\034"  
    
    x=($v)
    
    for ((y=0;y<${#x[@]};y++)); do
       [ "${x[y]::1}" == "_" ] && echo "$y: ${x[y]}"$'\n'
    done
}

declare -a _hints=()
declare _hint="start.hint"
declare _paths
declare _basepath="root/devops/cloud"
declare _base="/"
declare _hintmaxdepth=0

    echo "${BASH_VERSION}"

    getDeclared
```

***THIS OUTPUT***

```
➜  sometest bash working1.sh                                                                                                 
5.1.16(1)-release
0: BASH=/usr/local/bin/bash
```

Not what I expected.  If I change it to just echo everything (not filtering on the "_"), same result...

***THIS CODE ...***

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

getDeclared() {
    
    local v
    local x

    v=$( set -o posix ; set )
    IFS=$'\n' read -d '\034' -r -a v <<<"${v}\034"  
    
    x=($v)
    
    for ((y=0;y<${#x[@]};y++)); do
       echo "$y: ${x[y]}"$'\n'
    done
}

declare -a _hints=()
declare _hint="start.hint"
declare _paths
declare _basepath="root/devops/cloud"
declare _base="/"
declare _hintmaxdepth=0

    echo "${BASH_VERSION}"

    getDeclared
```

***HAS SAME OUTPUT***

```
➜  sometest bash working1.sh                                                                                                 
5.1.16(1)-release
0: BASH=/usr/local/bin/bash
```

Shellcheck just shows one warning on the `x=($v)` inside the function, saying to quote to prevent splitting.  But I don't see any difference when I do `x="($v)"` it just puts parens around the result as so:

```
➜  sometest bash working1.sh                                                                                                 
5.1.16(1)-release
0: (BASH=/usr/local/bin/bash)
```

What am I missing here?  Help!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Why do I get discrepencies between two code snippets?]

Because `$v` is only the first array element, so there is only one element inside `x`. If you want to copy an array, you should have used `x=("${v[@]}")`.

---

Just `-d ''` and prefer `mapfile`.

Comment: You are correct,  I guess I was getting confused when it returned the array as a single element.  Then trying to put it in the function, i was still thinking it was just one element aka string or w/e.

Comment: What does the `@` do as opposed to the `*`?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays `If the subscript is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the word expands to all members of the array name. These subscripts differ only when the word appears within double quotes. If the word is double-quoted, ${name[*]} expands to a single word with the value of each array member separated by the first character of the IFS variable, and ${name[@]} expands each element of name to a separate word` You can also find many bash arrays tutorials online. Consider using a less odd quirky langauge, like Python or perl.

Comment: Haha, I'm learning BASH because it is challenging.  Thanks for info/advice.  :)  What do they mean by "the word" ??   Is that array element, or maybe variable?  So name* = type string (if you will), and name@ = type array ???

Comment: errr...   (array)myvar=somearray[@] 
.........  (string)myvar=somearray[*]??   I do realize bash is not typed, but indulge me if you will, im coming from es6 .. php .. c  https://github.com/brianjpatterson/hintChallenge

Comment: `echo a     b` <- here `a` and `b` are separate words, separeate arguments. `echo 'a   b'` <- here `a     b` is a single word, single argument. `So name* = type string (if you will), and name@` yes, but in bash stuff has meaning _upon use_, not when defined. `"${name[@]}"` _expands_ to a list of words, `"${name[*]}"` _expands_ to a single word. `do realize bash is not typed` yes, in bash everything is a string.

Comment: That is a very good explanation.  Thank you.   Indeed difficult to get my head around even with a linux sysadmin and engineering background.   The challenge I linked on github has only been solved by 8 people on the site I'm using for challenges.   I hope to be the 9th.  LOL   I'm on my 5th wipe/restart after a month of ripping my hair out.  haha.   Thanks for insight/help :)  https://github.com/brianjpatterson/hintChallenge/blob/main/working.sh

Comment: I linked your SO profile in the Readme.md on github.   Submit a PR if you want it removed.  :)  LOL    or just comment here